# How can a pull a report with notes includes

Tags: contacts, database

We are trying to export a list with notes included. We are creating a prospect list for Employment Engagement team. We will add names to the database, this list is obtained from events that we host. We will then take the names and information add to Civi and use notes to personal our contact engagement. We will then want to pull and export a specific list that would include notes from previous interactions, so we can keep track of conversations

Answer (score 2):

Do a search to find the people who you want to pull information from, select the contacts and under actions select "export contacts." At step two select "select fields for export" and hit continue. Once on that page, choose any fields you want exported and there is an option for "Note(s)." I recommend saving the mapping so you do not have to choose which fields you want exported every time.